# Why does my mySql code take long time to execute?

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I have a table that holds few records less than 20. The table (`cow_inactive`) is just with ID (int) & COW_INACTIVE_DATE (varchar) columns. I am trying to use the DATEDIFF to get all cows that are ready for insemination after 60 Days of being inactive.

```
SELECT * from cow_inactive where DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, inactive_date)>=60
```

> Result :
> Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0022 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update field data type COW_INACTIVE_DATE (DATETIME). then run above query

Comment: Please seek to resolve questions using pre-existing pages first.  If a question is truly unique (this is very rare on Stack Overflow after millions of questions have been asked), then feel free to answer.